# How do I refer to the ID of a control in a different Content Panel?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASPX page with multiple Content panels.  In one panel is a RadioButtonList. In another panel is a data source that has a ControlParameter that references the RadioButtonList.  This worked fine when the list and the data source were in the same panel, but when I moved them to separate panels the ControlParameter could no longer find the RadioButtonList.

How do I modify the ID the ControlParameter is looking for so it can find it in the other panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer elsewhere:

Use the ID of the content panel, a dollar sign, and the ID of the control.

For example if the ControlParmeter looked like this when they were in the same panel:

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="tableName" Type="String"
     ControlID="rblCurrentEntityFriendlyName"
     PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
```

Then it would now look like this when the control was moved to a panel with ContentPlaceHolderID equal to `CPHEntityPanel`:

```
<asp:ControlParameter Name="tableName" Type="String"
         ControlID="CPHEntityPanel$rblCurrentEntityFriendlyName"
         PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
```

I got this answer from [Adrian Johnson](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/640fab4c-b0d0-44fc-9dd6-d711c1649b7b), who got it from "netneedsgiant, blog on May 5th 2006".